# ASP.NET MVC Custom Attributes within Custom View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

Assuming I write a custom attribute...

```
public class SpecialActionFilterAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // set some parameters here. 
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

And then I create a custom ViewEngine, and override FindView/FindPartialView...

```
    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        // how can I get those parameters here? 

        return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
    }
```

I'd like to be able to utilize the Custom Attribute to pass 'flags' of sorts to the custom view engine. is this at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
{
    var controller = controllerContext.Controller;

    var controllerType = controller.GetType();

    //now we can use reflection
    var attributes = controllerType.GetAttributes();

    // how can I get those parameters here? 

    return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
}
```