# Get Attribute value in ViewEngine ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, controller

I'm writting my own view engine.

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        // Here, how do I get attributes defined on top of the Action ?
    }    
}
```

[ASP.NET MVC Custom Attributes within Custom View Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976433/asp-net-mvc-custom-attributes-within-custom-view-engine)

Above SO Question has how to get attributes defined on top of the Controller. But I need to get attributes defined on Action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        var controllerType = controllerContext.Controller.GetType();
        var actionDescriptor = 
            new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType)
            .FindAction(
                controllerContext, 
                controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
            );
        var attributes = actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(...), false);

        // TODO: do something with the attributes that you retrieved
        // from the current action
    }    
}
```